# Issue with SQL Server 2014 Express Installation using Configuration File

Tags: sql-server, express

To help our IT department quickly install SQL Server 2014 Express in one click with all of our pertinent custom settings checked, I have created a 7-Zip self-Extracting .exe that extracts all the setup files, and then launches `Setup.exe` using the `/ConfigurationFile="config.ini"` option.

On most machines, the installation works perfectly; the files are automatically extracted into a temp directory, SQL Server is properly setup, and the temporary files are deleted. On about 20% of machines however, the SQL Server `Setup.exe` returns a bizarre error immediately after it launches. This usually seems to occur on Windows 7 Pro (SP1):

This is the error message:

> The following error occurred:
>   The action type 'ExecuteWorkflowAction' is not valid for the WorkflowIdentity element. The only valid action type is ExecuteWorkflowAction.
>   Error result: -2068709375
>   Result facility code: 1202
>   Result error code: 1

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On most of the machines that we installed this on, the username it was launched under was less than eight characters in length. In this case, the user name was more than eight characters, and thus causing the path to the `%TEMP%` directory to be passed in as an 8.3 filename format (`C:\Users\CONSOL~1`). For whatever reason, this seems to cause an issue with the SQL Server Setup program. To be more exact, I'd say this is more of an issue with the 7-Zip Self-extractor, however, I would still argue that the SQL Server Installer should be able to handle 8.3 filename formats. I created another user with less than eight characters, everything worked as expected.

Below is the post that helped me understand the issue:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/557341/sql-server-2008-r2-install-from-command-line